# delete last 3 columns from a file

Tags: shell, unix, sed, awk

I have a text file with 6 columns. How can I delete the last three columns from this file?

```
c1  c2  c3  c4  c5   c6
```

desired output

```
c1  c2  c3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use @paxdiablo's `awk` to reduce the value of `NF`

alternatively you can use `sed`

```
sed 's/\([ \t]\+[^ \t]*\)\{3\}$//' your_file
```

If you are on Linux, GNU `sed` provides `-r`

```
sed -r 's/([ \t]+[^ \t]*){3}$//' your_file
```

Comment: I thought of originally using that first trick but it unfortunately still leaves the spaces between fields. I think the better way is to simply reduce `NF` by 3.

Comment: Yes, saw your edit, instead of setting column to empty, reducing `NF` is much better, thanks.

Answer (score 8):

If spacing are not important, here is how to delete last 3 fields.

```
awk '{NF-=3}1' file
c1 c2 c3
```

---

You could even use

```
awk 'NF-=3' file
```

But its not as robust as the first example.

Answer (score 3):

To delete the last `N` columns in each row, you can simply reduce `NF` (the number of fields) by that amount, taking into account the special case where there aren't enough columns to delete):

```
pax> echo c1 c2 c3 c4 c5 c6 | awk -vN=3 '{if(NF<N){NF=0}else{NF-=N}print}'
c1 c2 c3
```

Keep in mind that `awk` is primarily a tool for processing columns of data. You'll notice that my output has a single space between fields since column-based processing doesn't usually care about the type of whitespace.

If spacing is important (ie, you want to preserve, for example, the number of spaces between columns), you should probably look into another tool.

Comment: +1 for this `awk`, previously I thought of setting last 3 columns to empty, that will leave space characters and it didn't take into consideration of lines with less than 3 columns, thanks. but instead of `'{if(NF<N){NF=0}else{NF-=N}print}'`, you can use `'{if(NF<N){NF=0}else{NF-=N}}1'`

Comment: This would change the spacing of the fields. (two spaces)

Comment: @Jotne, if you're processing fields, the white space between them can be _any_ white space. If you want to preserve them, you wouldn't be using a tool like `awk` which is meant for handling fields.

Comment: I know, I just comment that your output is not exactly as OPs output, and you should make a note to it.  Se my post.

Comment: @Jotne, now I understand. Clarified.

Answer (score 2):

If columns are separated by single space:

```
cut -d " " -f1-3 file
```

If columns are separated by multiple space:

```
tr -s " " file | cut -d " " -f1-3
```

If columns are separated by tab:

```
cut -f1-3 file
```

Answer (score -1):

`awk '{print $1 " "  $2 " " $3}' filename > filename.new`

Comment: @Hamad OP does not say how to get the result, so this is as good as any other post here.  He only says `delete last 3 columns from a file` and this does it.  Same as `Backspace` does :)

Answer (score -1):

Pure bash (if spacing is not important):

```
tr -s ' ' < file | rev | cut -d' ' -f4- | rev
```

use `cut -d' ' -f5-` if there are trailing space(s), or trim trailing spaces before these.

But I do like the Jotne/paxdiablo's awk NF solution much better.